# Would a full back up (from recovery) preserve all data including installed apps?

Tags: backup, clockworkmod-recovery, recovery-mode

I wonder if I create a full back up from recovery, would it preserve all my data? Including installed apps (along with their configs) and my contacts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are talking about a Nandroid backup: Yes, it would. It creates images from the devices file systems -- so all that's stored there gets copied to those image files. You can then even extract single items using e.g. [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup).